# Why does execution of a command need disk space

Tags: linux, ssh, disk-usage

We manage several Linux boxes remotely through SSH, recently one of them filled up disk space to the point that the people logged in couldn't execute commands at all, and the person in charge of fixing the issue was unable to even log in through SSH.

Thankfully, we were able to restore to an earlier state prior to the disk filling up completely and work backwards.

I'm not in charge of the box so the laughs are for someone else, but a request for a technical explanation came up. Why does this happen, simple commands like ls and rm wouldn't even function. I assume it has something to do with needing temporary space to process commands but would be interested in whatever insight you can provide.

Comment: Were you getting a "no space left on device" error with these commands that failed or did they just hang and give no error?

Comment: Yeah I think that was the error, or at least an equivalent, there was no hanging, simply rejected

Comment: Ah. Please [edit] that into your question. Also tell us what OS and distribution, if Linux, what shell and what specific commands (or some, at least) were failing with this error.

Comment: I'd first ask about the type of filesystem used.
Depending on the filesystem and parameters used when making it, some minimal amount of space is kept free in order to prevent the problem you experienced.
Considering an EXT4, the parameter is labeled "reserved_ratio".
As, as far as EXT4 is concerned, it is a percentage of the number of blocks of the filesystem. Considering that filesystems are nowadays very large, the default (5%) represents a very comfortable margin.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that `rm` would fail. Running `rm` through `strace` does not show any use of temporary files.

But many shell scripts run into problems. For example, here documents cannot be executed if `/tmp` is not writable any more (due to lack of space). This may lead to the failure of an SSH login attempt.

### for the future

If that happens again:

- It may be interesting to run `rm` through `strace` in order to better understand what is happening: `strace rm file`.
- You do not have to delete a file, not even to call an external command to free space: Instead of `rm file` you can do this in a shell: `: >file`. That reduces the file size to 0. It does not free the inode, though.

Comment: Did you try with a directory with very many files? Could it be using some sort of temp file to store while it sorts through the results?

Comment: That was my thinking also, maybe there's some disk usage needed to store output for stdout or something, the rm command failed to remove even a single file from the temp directory, and we couldn't get a file list from ls which made it seemingly impossible to resolve from ssh. The root owner tried to login after but his login window immediately closed after authentication which was kind of expected at that point.

Comment: @terdon No, I did not. I don't see why that should be the case, though. Why should the directory content be sorted before being deleted? The order in which the entries are read is the optimal order for deletion. And even if there was such a situation: That would not be the same as "rm does not work any more".

Comment: @frozenthorn I consider that very improbable. You can boot Linux with read-only volumes and the ttys/ptys do work as usual. Maybe there was an alias or a shell function `rm`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes indeed. I was thinking of `ls`, not `rm`. I must have read the first `ls` in your answer and then didn't realize the rest of your answer was more focused on `rm`. My bad.